# awk to a pattern position length

Tags: awk

enter code here[image]Looking for a solution to compact the log output I'm receiving. I'm only needing the column info before CLEARED_TIME and disregard the output after ALARM_GROUP. The columns width do expand and contract at times. Also fields number from CLEARD_TIME are not static, there could be clear date output or it's a dash.

Solution Found :

```
TOVYILAABBULTE0491808 RTRV-ALM-LOG | gawk '/LOG_NO/,/COUNT/ {if ($1 == "LOG_NO") p = index($0,"ALARM_GROUP")-1} {if ($1 == "LOG_NO") print substr($0,1,p)} {if ($2 == "RRH" && $3 == "COMMUNICATION_FAIL" ) print substr($0,1,p)}'

Current Output :
   LOG_NO   UNIT_TYPE   ALARM_TYPE                   LOCATION                        RAISED_TIME           CLEARED_TIME          ALARM_GROUP       PROBABLE_CAUSE        SEVERITY   ALARM_CODE
   2        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 06:06:49   2019-03-19 06:06:58   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   3        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 06:38:29   2019-03-19 06:38:38   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   8        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 07:47:59   2019-03-19 07:48:38   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   9        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_8_0]-RRH[0_8_0]           2019-03-19 07:54:39   -                     EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   10       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 09:15:59   2019-03-19 09:16:28   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   11       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 14:13:49   2019-03-19 14:14:18   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   12       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 15:10:09   -                     EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   13       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 15:48:19   2019-03-19 15:48:48   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   14       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 17:47:59   2019-03-19 17:48:08   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   
   15       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 18:01:29   2019-03-19 18:03:18   EQUIPMENT_ALARM   LINK_FAILURE          major      3149381   

Desired Output : 
   LOG_NO   UNIT_TYPE   ALARM_TYPE                   LOCATION                        RAISED_TIME           CLEARED_TIME       
   2        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 06:06:49   2019-03-19 06:06:58
   3        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 06:38:29   2019-03-19 06:38:38
   8        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 07:47:59   2019-03-19 07:48:38
   9        RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_8_0]-RRH[0_8_0]           2019-03-19 07:54:39   -
   10       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 09:15:59   2019-03-19 09:16:28
   11       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 14:13:49   2019-03-19 14:14:18
   12       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_10_0]-RRH[0_10_0]         2019-03-19 15:10:09   -
   13       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 15:48:19   2019-03-19 15:48:48
   14       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 17:47:59   2019-03-19 17:48:08
   15       RRH         COMMUNICATION_FAIL           RRH[0_4_0]-RRH[0_4_0]           2019-03-19 18:01:29   2019-03-19 18:03:18
```

Comment: Please, post some textual sample data with the expected output for testing.

Comment: I include an image because the text wrap when posting.

Comment: Use the `{}` "button" in the editor for data or add 4 spaces before each data row. Images are useless in here.

Comment: Now my downvote, btw.

Comment: Downvoters, you do realize that there is posted the sample data (since `print $0`), expected output and the code OP's been using, the one he hopes help with.

Comment: @JamesBrown no, I just see an image of some kind and then current and expected output. I don't see the sample input that would be used to produce that output.

Comment: Sorry, busy doing something, can't hold anymore hands. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that data the simplest solution is to replace the `print $0` with `print substr($0,1,126)` and tune those parameters to your liking in case they are not correct.

Comment: I used you solution and added index to a if statement to locate "ALARM_GROUP" value.

Comment: TOVYILAABBULTE0491808 RTRV-ALM-LOG | gawk '/LOG_NO/,/COUNT/ {if ($1 == "LOG_NO") p = index($0,"ALARM_GROUP")-1} {if ($1 == "LOG_NO") print substr($0,1,p)} {if ($2 == "RRH" && $3 == "COMMUNICATION_FAIL" ) print substr($0,1,p)}'

Comment: I have the output that I need